# Why does 'sudo java' change the user home directory to /root?

Tags: command-line, permissions, java, sudo

I have a program that needs to access a file in my home directory.

Ubuntu will not allow this to happen due to the program not having root privileges. At first I ran this java command (which wouldn't work because the program did not have permission to access the files):

```
java -jar this.jar
```

The program was unable to detect the file I needed it to. The path that the program told me that it used was `/home/myhome/directory`. This path was correct.
But then the program needed root privileges to actually access that file so I tried:

```
sudo java -jar this.jar
```

Then the directory that the program tried to access was `/root/directory` this is the problem that I am having.

Is there any way that I can run a program as root with the directory the program views as the `home` directory being the `/home` directory instead of the `/root` directory?

Comment: Which user is executing the command? If it is you the program should be able to access your home.

Comment: I will be executing the command, but i need to give the command root privilages in order for the program to actually work. Ive attempted "sudo -u me mycommand" to set the user as me, but sudo then executes the command without root privilage (it doesnt ask me for my root password)

Comment: Try : `  $ sudo HOME=/home/your-user-name java -jar this.jar  ` your program will be run with sudo privileges, while sudo will perceive its `HOME` as being whatever path you give it as home. If this is not what you are asking for, then I did not understand your question. Let us know if this works.

Comment: @Cbhihe That's the same as running `sudo` without the `-H` option; try running `sudo echo $HOME`. If `sudo` it's not explicitly told to set the environment differently, the environment from which `sudo` is invoked it's retained during the command execution. That's also the reason why running graphical applications with `sudo` is discouraged, because root might end up owning files in the home directory, and also the reason why I think the problem is another one.

Comment: @kos: yes, I know. OP is rather cryptic about his/her  default sudo security policy so I wanted to try this. I do not understand why when invoking `sudo`,  `HOME` suddenly becomes that of `root`. My system does not show that behavior at all. At Sock314: did you try this yet ?

Comment: @Cbhihe In fact that's strange. It looks like the java program it's determining the home folder based on something else (which I guess it would be the user running it?) than the environment... @ Sock314 Can you tell us which program is this one?

Comment: Is there any reason `/home/myhome/directory` isn't owned by you? Are you sure running a program as `root` just to access a directory in your own folder is the right solution?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because you are dealing with a Java program, you specify the directory it should see as the home directory by setting the system property `user.home`:

```
sudo java -Duser.home=$HOME -jar this.jar
```

It is confusing that this should be necessary. Since `sudo` by default retains the value of `HOME`, one would expect Java to set `user.home` to `$HOME`. However, the [Java API documentation for `java.lang.System`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html)  states that `user.home` will be set to *User's home directory*. It does not state that it will be set to the value of the `HOME` environment variable -- which indeed may or may not be the user's home directory.

Note, as has been pointed out in the comments, that it is not recommended to run software as root. If you do, then give it a dedicated working directory, i.e. set its `user.home` to some location reserved for it.

Comment: @Sock314: looks like you went off fishing. Not good form. Please attend people who attend you.  @ zwets: +1, most interesting. I did not know that. It would explain the value of HOME being root's when running `sudo java -jar ... ` since `root` owns the process. Let's see what Socks314 has to say.

Comment: Ah that makes sense! +1. So how is the home directory normally set when running a java program? Based on the user running the program?

Comment: @Cbhihe No, HOME will be the home directory of the user invoking `sudo`. You can check this by executing `echo 'public class T1 { public static void main(String[] args) { System.out.println(System.getenv("HOME")); } }' > T1.java && javac T1.java && sudo java T1`. This will yield **/home/user**. The issue is that Java ignores HOME when setting **user.home**.  Now execute `echo 'public class T2 { public static void main(String[] args) { System.out.println(System.getProperty("user.home")); } }' > T2.java && javac T2.java && sudo java T2`, and this will yield **/root**.

Comment: @kos The Java [API documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html) for `java.lang.System` states that `user.home` is set to *User's home directory*. I would then assume that it obtains this via the POSIX standard call `getpwuid(getuid())->pw_dir`, not via the `HOME` environment variable, which may or may not be set to the effective user's home directory. This makes sense, really. It is *sudo* which is the 'odd one out' here.